# Use the indexOf() method of Vector in java to match a member variable

Tags: java, vector, contains

Here's my code:

```
String name = "John Doe";

int result = vec.indexOf(name);
```

Keeping in mind that vec is a vector of MyClass objects, and MyClass contains a member variable called name. I am passing in a string instead of a MyClass object because I want to match an object that has the same name as its member variable. Is this possible. I have even tried to override the toString() function in MyClass to return the name, it still doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try ```boolean result = vec.stream().anyMatch(e -> e.getName().equals(name));```.

Comment: Error 'Lamda expressions are not supported at this language level'

Comment: @user2218567, did any of these answer accomplish what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Jus overriding toString() method will not do the work.You need to Override equals method of MyClass and you should pass the MyClass obj to vector.contains() method. Please find below code.

Override equals method like this.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    boolean retVar = false;
    if (obj instanceof MyClass){
        MyClass object = (MyClass) obj;
        retVar = object.getName().equals(this.name);
    }
    return retVar;
}
```

When calling you vector contains Method do as follows.

```
Vector<MyClass> vector = new Vector<MyClass>();
vector.add(new MyClass("Alpha"));
vector.add(new MyClass("Beta"));
vector.add(new MyClass("Gamma"));

MyClass myClass = new MyClass("Alpha");
boolean res = vector.contains(myClass);
System.out.println("Vector contains " + myClass.getName() + " = " + res);
```

Result :
Vector contains Alpha = true

Comment: This is good, but the only problem is that I can't pass in an entire object. I only know the name variable of the object which is a string. I want to match the object based on that. So I need to use contains() and indexOf() to get the index.

Answer (score 0):

From what i gather, you simply want to check if the name stored in a String you have matches the 'name' member of any 'MyClass` object.
 Why not create your own method for it ? I have created a constructor in MyClass where i pass a string as an argument during initialization which assigns the object it's 'name'.
 After that, simply create a new method that iterates through the vector and returns *true* if the 'name' of any object matches the argument to passed to check:

The class:

```
class MyClass
{
    String name;
    MyClass(String name)
    {
        this.name=name;
    }
}
```

```
//Inside your relevant function (could be main)
Vector<MyClass> v=new Vector<MyClass>();
v.add(new MyClass("John"));
v.add(new MyClass("Harry"));
String name="John";
boolean res=checkName(v,name);
```

Function to check:

```
boolean checkName(Vector<MyClass> v,String name)
{
    for(MyClass check:v)
        if(check.name.equals(name))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```